# What should the Euro regulators look for and monitor to prevent a Euro crisis?

Tags: macroeconomics, financial-crises

What should the Euro regulators look for and monitor to prevent a Euro crisis?

Comment: What is a "Euro regulator" and what is a "Euro crisis"?

Answer (score 1):

For an EU member state to joins and stays in the [Eurozone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurozone) (the official name of what you called the Euro Club), it is necessary to comply with the [Stability and Growth Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_and_Growth_Pact) (which Bulgaria already does) and fulfill the [Euro Convergence Criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_convergence_criteria) defined in the Maastricht treaty [article 140](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Consolidated_version_of_the_Treaty_on_the_Functioning_of_the_European_Union/Title_VIII:_Economic_and_Monetary_Policy#Article_140).

In a nutshell, the convergence criteria define targets for the country on inflation, public debt deficit, interest rates and exchange rate against the Euro. These targets should be followed for a certain duration of time.

All of these targets were put in place to monitor and prevent economic instability - and after the debt crisis in several member states (such as Greece) these indicators keep on being used as good indicators to **monitor** the stability of a country's economy. However, **preventing** a economic crisis would require a higher integration of the member states, such as a Euro-zone public budget.